# TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So, I am trying to make a simple ping command, but it is throwing an error. It is saying that the app crashed and that it cannot read the property of 'set'. I am so confused by this. If you can help, please do. I am semi-new to coding, so yeah.

```js
const Client = require('../structures/Client');
const { Message } = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: `ping`,
    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        const msg = await message.channel.send(`Pinging...`);
        await msg.edit(client.embed({
            title: `Pong!`,
            description: `Websocket ping is ${client.ws.ping}MS\nMessage edit ping is ${msg.createdAt - message.createdAt}MS!`
        }, message));
    }
}
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
            this.commands.set(File.name, File)
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at C:\Users\prick\Desktop\bot\structures\Client.js:14:27
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at GiveawayClient.commandHandler (C:\Users\prick\Desktop\bot\structures\Client.js:12:68)
    at GiveawayClient.start (C:\Users\prick\Desktop\bot\structures\Client.js:18:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\prick\Desktop\bot\index.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Client.js:

````
const { Collection, Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
class GiveawayClient extends Client {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.giveaways = new Collection();
        this.ms = require('ms');
        this.fs = require('fs');
        this.path = require('path');
        this.discord = require('discord.js');
    }
    commandHandler(path) {
        this.fs.readdirSync(this.path.join(__dirname, `..`, path)).map((f) => {
            let File = require(this.path.join(__dirname, `..`, path, f));
            this.commands.set(File.name, File)
        })
    };
    start(token, path) {
        this.commandHandler(path);
        this.login(token);
        this.on('ready', () => {
            console.log(`${this.user.username} is online, bitch!`);
        });
        this.on('message', async(message) => {
            if(message.author.bot || !message.guild || !message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`!!`)) return;
            const args = message.content.slice(`!!`.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
            const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
            if(this.commands.has(cmd)) this.commands.get(cmd).run(this, message, args).catch(console.error)
        });
    }
    embed(data, message) {
        return new MessageEmbed(data).setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({dnyamic: true }))
    }
}
module.exports = GiveawayClient;```
````

Comment: You haven't included the relevant code (Client.js).

Comment: @jarmod Updated! Sorry about that!

Comment: I'm guessing that `this.commands = new Collection()` is required in your constructor, unless you intended to use `this.giveaways` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put a breakpoint on the line having an error to see what value `this.commands` is set to?

I'd guess it's not set to anything, which would mean it's "undefined" and you can't use an object property if there's no object there to have a property.

The short answer is to check to see if `this.commands` has a value before trying to use it.

```
if (this.commands)
{
    this.commands.set(File.name, File)
}
```

The long answer includes making sure that you have checked the values of your variables, as well as doing other research on what the error means, before posting a question here.

You should check out the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure you aren't getting down voted or votes to close your question.

We were all beginners at programming and Stack Exchange at some point. Just make sure you are doing due diligence to avoid making people cranky. Asking questions is good, just make sure you are asking questions that haven't been answered before.